# ASP.NET Core 6.0: Is it possible to access the controller instance from IModelBinder.BindModelAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

In ASP.NET MVC (on .NET 4.8) I have:

```
public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (bindingContext == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

    var controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as AppController;
   
    if (controller == null)
        return true;
    // ....
}
```

The controller context has the [controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.controller?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-controllercontext-controller) property through which I can get the instance of the controller.

How can I access in asp.net core 6.0 the instance of the controller being executed inside [BindModelAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.imodelbinder.bindmodelasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0) ? None of the objects  passed in the `ModelBindingContext` parameter seem point to the instance of the controller, unless I missed something. Here is the [controller context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllercontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0) doc. The [`ControllerContext.ControllerActionDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-6.0) points to anything but the instance of the controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try as below to get an instance of the controller:

```
var factory= bindingContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IControllerFactory>();
var controllercontext = bindingContext.ActionContext as ControllerContext;
//add null check before this line
var controllerinstance = factory.CreateController(controllercontext);
```

Comment: Does `factory.CreateController(controllercontext)` create the controller or get the controller?

Comment: It will  create a copy of the current controller,you want the  intance of the current controller?What's your further requirement?

Comment: I am converting an app from .net framework to .net core, and I have this binder that calls a method implemented by the controller (the controller inherits  the method from a common class). I guess I could move that method to a service and get the service via DI but I was wondering of it's still possible to get the controller instance as it's done in .Net 4.8.

Comment: All controllers  inherit from ControllerBase class now,I  think you have to move the method into a service and get the service from di container